# In what sense is the nesher connected to geulah?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, words, animals, parashat-shemini, messianic-redemption

[Parshas shemini](http://hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_35966_77.pdf) lists the nesher (*vulture*?) as non-kosher animal. But Ieshaiahu describes the future geulah connecting the tzadikim with neshirim (ישעיה מ:לא). Also, [Sforno in parshas haazinu](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40007&st=&pgnum=137&hilite=) alludes this:

> כַּאֲשֶׁר אֶתְפַּלֵּל עַל קִבּוּץ גָּלֻיּוֹת, בְּאָמְרִי "כַּנֶּשֶׁר
>   יָעִיר קִנּוֹ" ,
>
> (Moshe rabeinu) says: when I pray on regard Kibbutz Galuyos saying, "as a
>   nesher that stirs up in its nest..."

It seems to carry a "negative connotation" in Shemini and a positive connotation in Sforno and Ieshaiahu. I feel like I'm missing something here.

Comment: The brachot of Yaakov to his sons mention leo,  wolf,  snake,  hamor...  Eating is not the unique criterion

Comment: Just because the nesher is not a kosher bird does not mean that its power and ability to flie high is to be disparaged. Consider "on the wings of eagles" as a mashal.